# How to dynamically create css for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a html text received from server, as follows:

```
<html>
...
<span class="foo">sample text</span>
...
```

And I rendered the html text with React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```js
const Foo = () => {
  let html = `
  <html>
  ...
  <span class="foo">sample text</span>
  `
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
  )
}
```

How to apply style to `<span class="foo">sample text</span>` dynamically?
The reason why I want to do it "dynamically" is that I want to change the style when some button is pushed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know ahead of time the class names you'll be dynamically overriding? Would a string regex find/replace work?

Comment: Yes, I know the class names ahead of time, and regex works. However I want to know how to modify css if it is possible, because I think it is more robust.

Comment: So are you saying you've tried what I've suggested? Something else? Using a regex allows you to change the class in the html string?

Comment: Yes, I tried with regex and it works. Now I'm trying jss.

Answer (score 0):

Create external logic in `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount()`. And change classes/styles with JavaScript with DOM API (addEventListener, removeEventListener). You are not using React to create that HTML code so your options are limited by that.

Comment: Is not react-jss suitable?

Comment: When you put HTML in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you don't use JSX and onChange added directly to `<span class="foo">` will not work. Also `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is called dangerously because HTML inside can be broken (div without closing tag `</div>`) .

Comment: You can add onClick to the parent and gather clicks from the rendered content (because they will propagate up in DOM tree) but I would not say that it is cleaner than what I mentioned above. If you are using DOM listeners in `useEffect()` other developers know that you are working with external content.